# Launching thread through Constructor in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, api, sockets, c++11

I am trying to execute the program where I create a queue of packaged_task and try to execute the packaged_tasks in a separate thread. I am getting the following error

***Error    C2664   'std::function<_Ret (void)>::function(std::function<_Ret (void)> &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::_Binder' to 'std::nullptr_t'***

The code I have is shown below. Could any one guide as to why this error happens ?

```
/*
****************************************************************************************************
                                        The Header File
****************************************************************************************************
*/


class CommandChannel {
private:
    std::thread commChannelThread;
    std::mutex commChannelmu;
    std::condition_variable commChannelcv;


    struct taskRequest
    {};
    struct taskResponse
    {};

    /* Creates a queue of packaged tasks that accepts one iu */
    std::deque< std::packaged_task<int()>> comm_ch_task_queue;

    void threadHandler(void);

protected:
    int p_impl_theAdd(int a, int b);
    int p_impl_theMul(int a, int b);
    int p_impl_theDiv(int a, int b);
public:
    /*Constructor and the Destructor*/
    CommandChannel();
    ~CommandChannel();

    /*The public functions */
    int theAdd(int a, int b);
    int theMul(int a, int b);
    int theDiv(int a, int b);
};

    /*
    ****************************************************************************************************
                                            The Implementation File
    ****************************************************************************************************
    */

/* Implementation Functions */
int CommandChannel::p_impl_theAdd(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

int CommandChannel::p_impl_theMul(int a, int b)
{
    return a*b;
}

int CommandChannel::p_impl_theDiv(int a, int b)
{
    return a / b;
}


/* COnstructors and Destructors */
CommandChannel::CommandChannel()
{
    /*Creating a new thread that runs the threadHandler function*/
    commChannelThread = std::thread(&CommandChannel::threadHandler, this);
}
CommandChannel::~CommandChannel()
{
    if (commChannelThread.joinable()) {
        commChannelThread.join();
        std::cout << "Command Channel Thread Joined " << std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Problem in joining the Command Channel Thread" << std ::endl;
}

/*  User Public Functions  */
int CommandChannel::theAdd(int a, int b)
{
    /* Creating the packaged task with the the implementation pointer */
    std::packaged_task<int()> t(std::bind(&CommandChannel::p_impl_theAdd, a, b));

    /* Pushing the task in the queue */
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(commChannelmu);
        comm_ch_task_queue.push_back(t);
        commChannelcv.notify_one();
    }

    /* creating the placeholder for the return value */
    std::future<int> fu = t.get_future();

    /* getting the value from the future */
    return fu.get();

}

int CommandChannel::theMul(int a, int b)
{
    /* Create the packaged task with the pimpl */
    std::packaged_task<int()> t(std::bind(&CommandChannel::p_impl_theMul, a, b));

    /* Pushing the task in the queue */
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(commChannelmu);
        comm_ch_task_queue.push_back(t);
        commChannelcv.notify_one();
    }

    /* Creating the placeholder for the return value */
    std::future<int> fu = t.get_future();

    /*getting the value from the future*/
    return fu.get();
}

int CommandChannel::theDiv(int a, int b)
{
    /* Create the packaged tasks with the pimpl */
    std::packaged_task<int()> t(std::bind(&CommandChannel::p_impl_theDiv, a, b));

    /*Pushing the task in the queue thorigh the mutex locks*/
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(commChannelmu);
        comm_ch_task_queue.push_back(t);
        commChannelcv.notify_one();
    }
    /* Creating the placeholder for the return value */
    std::future<int> fu = t.get_future();

    /*getting the value from the future*/
    return fu.get();
}


/* 
   Thread Handler

   Pops the elemetns from the queue and then executes them
   the value goes to the called function through future references
*/
void CommandChannel::threadHandler()
{
    std::packaged_task<int()> t;
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(commChannelmu);
        commChannelcv.wait(locker);
        t = std::move(comm_ch_task_queue.front());
        comm_ch_task_queue.pop_front();
    }
    t();
}


    /*
    ****************************************************************************************************
                                            Main
    ****************************************************************************************************
    */

int main()
{
    CommandChannel api;

    api.theAdd(2, 4);
    api.theDiv(6, 3);
    api.theMul(5, 7);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: don't use bind, use a lambda instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding non-static member function of class,
so you need to specify the object for which
member function is called. `this` is missing 
in all calls of `bind`:

```
std::packaged_task<int()> t(std::bind(&CommandChannel::p_impl_theDiv, this, a, b));
```

do the same for `theMul` and `theAdd`.

Second problem, `packaged_task` object cannot be copied,
if you want to pass this object as parameter of 
`push_back` you have to cast `packaged_task` object 
to Rvalue reference, then `packaged_task` will be moved
into vector.

```
comm_ch_task_queue.push_back(std::move(t));
```

All above is to eliminate errors during compilation.

1) 
Because `packaged_task` is moved in `theDiv` method,
you cannot call any members for this object after move operation was performed.
After pushing `packaged_task` you should leave from `theDiv` function.

```
void CommandChannel::theDiv(int a, int b)
{
    /* Create the packaged tasks with the pimpl */
    std::packaged_task<int()> t(std::bind(&CommandChannel::p_impl_theDiv, this, a, b));

    /*Pushing the task in the queue thorigh the mutex locks*/
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(commChannelmu);
        comm_ch_task_queue.push_back(std::move(t));
        commChannelcv.notify_one();
    }

    // access to t is forbidden
}
```

Do the same with `theAdd` and `theMul` methods.

2) Your thread function performs only one task from queue. 
I think some loop is missing there. You want to execute all incoming tasks into queue (details in comments):

```
void CommandChannel::threadHandler()
{
    std::packaged_task<int()> t;
    while (true) // inifite loop to process incoming tasks
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(commChannelmu);
        commChannelcv.wait(locker,[this](){ return comm_ch_task_queue.size();});
        // wait returns if there is some task to be performed

        t = std::move(comm_ch_task_queue.front());
        comm_ch_task_queue.pop_front();
        std::future<int> f = t.get_future();
        t(); // perform task
        std::cout << f.get() << std::endl; // print value
    }
}
```

Comment: @rafixx07 In this implementation the theAdd function ( theMul and theDiv too) do not return any value. What if I want to exchange the return value from the thread Handler to the theAdd function?

Comment: @D_wanna_B_coder If i understand correctly: you want to create task, push task into queue, and wait in `theAdd` until task is performed in `Handler` thread, then read value from future and returns from theAdd ?
In order to do it you need to call `std::future<int> fu = t.get_future();`
before `{LOCK; comm_ch_task_queue.push_back(move(t)); NOTIFY_ONE}`:
so you get future, packaged_task is moved into queue, then you wait 
for shared state is ready in future. In Handler you need to only read packaged_task, call `()` on task and remove task from queue. In Handler you cannot use future then.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted and now the code works.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your code. First, you are using your binders incorrectly. When binding a member function, first argument should have the pointer to the class, in your case `this`. Here is one example of fixed code:

```
std::packaged_task<int()> t(std::bind(&CommandChannel::p_impl_theDiv, this, a, b));
```

However, using lambdas is usually much more intuitive and syntax-friendly than binders. Here is the same idea expressed with lambda:

```
std::packaged_task<int()> t([this, a, b]() {return p_impl_theDiv(a, b);});
```

Also, once this is fixed everywhere, you will have another problem - you are copying `packaged_task` objects while pushing them to queue. Those objects are not copyable, you have to move instead. Again, here is one instance of this fixed:

```
comm_ch_task_queue.push_back(std::move(t));
```

There might be other issues with this code, I only fixed compilation errors.